# Do they check ARD ZDF bill payment during de-registration in Frankfurt if a person is leaving the country?

Tags: germany

I came to Frankfurt in Jul 2019. I lived in an apartment from Jul'19-Feb'20.
During this period, I had some amount to pay to ARD ZDF.

Eight months after moving to a new apartment (Oct'20), I de-registered from my previous contribution number and registered to my new landlord's contribution number (I live in WG apartment and owner pays the ARD ZDF bill).

During this period from (Mar'20-Oct'20), I received the ARD bill at my new address but with my old contribution number.

Now in Oct'20, I received a letter from ARD saying to pay the balance through FEB'20.

I did so, and after 3 days, I received a letter saying that my contribution number account is balanced.

I asked them the same thing on a phone call and was informed I don't have to pay anything. But somehow I am not convinced.

So my question is: while doing a de-registration, will the city office check if any amount is pending from ARD in my name?

Also, if de-registration is given to me from the city office, will that mean I am all good in ARD ZDF's books?

Answer (score 3):

The registration office does not have access to your GEZ bill. They cannot deny you deregistration, but also cannot tell you whether your debts are settled.

You might prefer to clarify this matter with the GEZ in writing rather than over phone, since you can more easily machine-translate an email or letter.

Comment: It's now called "ARD ZDF Deutschlandradio Beitragsservice" and "Rundfunkbeitrag". GEZ is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

You can always de-register and move out of country, even if you have debt with GEZ. The registration office may forward your data to GEZ but apart from that, they won't care about your TV licensing.

Btw, you don't need to come to the registration office in person to deregister. You can just download the deregistration form, fill it in and mail it to the registration office.

What you should do though is to notify GEZ that you have given up your previous home (so you aren't subject to TV licensing fees anymore) and give them your new address so they can contact you in your new country in case of any unfinished business.